# How to invoke ioctl in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ioctl

I'm trying to execute an ioctl call on a system with only bash and primitive base utilities.

Is there any way to execute arbitrary ioctl command (if the params are simply integers) to a specific device file in /dev in shell script, without writing C / perl / python programs? Something like
 "magic_ioctl /dev/console 30 1 2" which would calls "ioctl(open("/dev/console"), 30, 1, 2);".

Comment: you could see whether your driver has a sysfs interface.

Comment: Seems like you could write a trivial C program to do this.

Comment: Being able to issue `ioctl` calls in, for example, init scripts on embedded devices (no perl/python), without having to deal with cross-compilation/deployment of a C program (just one line in the script!) would be really handy. Did you manage to get any further with this?

Answer (score 14):

I wrote `ioctl` tool exactly for this purpose: https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/ioctl.

Currently, it is not possible to pass multiple argument to ioctl call. Have you an example where it would be usefull?

If you want to call `ioctl(open("/dev/console"), 30, 1);`, you can run:

```
ioctl /dev/console 30 -v 1
```

However, for most ioctl, you want to allocate a buffer and pass a pointer to this buffer in argument to ioctl call. In this case, just forget `-v`. `ioctl` will read/write buffer content from/to standard input/output. `ioctl` try to guess buffer size and direction from ioctl number.

The best is: `ioctl` understand many (around 2200) ioctl symbolic names. Thus you can call:

```
ioctl /dev/video0 VIDIOC_QUERYCAP > video_caps
```

Comment: Found similarly named stock utility in my android 2.3 at /system/bin/ioctl.

Comment: @ogurets: interesting, do you know where is source code of this utility?

Comment: I think this is the one: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4_r1/toolbox/ioctl.c

Comment: What if you want to run ioctl on an existing file descriptor without opening?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda No, it is not supported. However, the feature is not complicated.Patches welcome. Don't forget to provide a usage example (playing with file descriptors in shell is not obvious).

Comment: Is this ioctl program still maintained? Looks like GitHub PRs are not being processed.

Comment: @AlexD Indeed, `ioctl` would need some attention. I will do the housework next week.

Answer (score 7):

Why you reject perl/c/python solutions ?
You can made this by perl one-liner like this:
`perl -e require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(...);`

Comment: There are reasons.  E.g. on my target platform, there's no perl/python at all.  And creating a C program for this purpose is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I don't want to recompile the C everytime the system changes.